# Is there any available dataset describing types of sensors (ideally using SSNO)?

Tags: data-request, standards, rdf, ontology

I am developing an application that tries to predict what type of sensors would be needed in a working environment to achieve certain goals.

In order to function, this application needs to know (A) what type of sensors exist, and (B) what they measure.
For example, it would be useful for me to know which type of sensors are available to measure CO2 gas concentration, or temperatures, or vibrations.

I could, of course, search for available sensors myself on the web, and create a dataset with their main characteristics.

But I was wondering if such data already exists in some form.

I am particularly interested in datasets following the Semantic Sensor Network Ontology (SSNO). SSNO can be used to describe types of sensors, but so far I have not managed to find any dataset containing such descriptions (beyond a few toy examples).

I know that I won't be able to find a comprehensive list of all the possible sensors, but I am interested in such datasets even if they are not very complete/accurate/updated...

Comment: Possibly related (though obviously outdated): https://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/ssn/wiki/Sensor_types